# How do I line up list bullets in CSS?

Tags: html, css, list

So these bullets I have in this list are uneven and I want them to be even. I came across the answer some time ago but I could not find it for the life of me now. Any help is appreciated.

```css
#div1 {
  border: black;
  border-style: inset;
  margin-top: 5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.div2 {
  border: blue;
  border-style: inset;
  height: 100%;
}

#salty {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 45em;
  height: 50em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-1"></div>

    <div class="col-md-10" id="div1">
      <p id="p1">
        <h1>My Cat Salty</h1>
      </p>
      <p id="p2">
        <h2>Salty is a floofball</h2>
      </p>

      <div class="div2"><img src="babysalty.jpg" id="salty" />
        <p id="p3"> This is my cat, Salty. </p>
      </div>

      <div class="div3">
        <ul>
          <li>Salty is a cat.</li>
          <li>This is a list item.</li>
          <li>This is a list item.</li>
          <li>Salty is fluffy.</li>
          <li>This is a list item.</li>
          <li>This is a list item.</li>
          <li>Salty also has a fluffy tail.</li>
          <li>This is a list item.</li>
</ul>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And for some reason I can't get my CSS to display in the post so it's in the JSFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/dus0tLyt/4/

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Your `ul` is never closed.

Comment: +1 because you included a [MCVE], explained your problem clearly, and made it relatively easy to see your problem.

Comment: I dont see how this is *minimal*.

Comment: @connexo pretty close. I mean, he could slim it down a little, but he doesn't have `<head>` etc

Comment: Fixed the <ul> thing, sorry. Yeah I didn't post ALL of the HTML, just the meaty body code. The rest is the normal html code stuff and links to bootstrap/my css. Thanks for the assist with the CSS btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `ul` an `inline-block` and `text-align` the list items `left`.

```css
.div3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.div3 ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.div3 ul li {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="div3">
  <ul>
    <li>Salty is a cat.</li>
    <li>This is a list item.</li>
    <li>This is a list item.</li>
    <li>Salty is fluffy.</li>
    <li>This is a list item.</li>
    <li>This is a list item.</li>
    <li>Salty also has a fluffy tail.</li>
    <li>This is a list item.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh man, excellent. That was way less code than I thought I needed as well, thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to upvote, but don't omit picking the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to close your `<ul>` tag using `</ul>`.

The reason your `<li>` is not even is that the styling for `<ul>` is `text-align: center;`. Try to change it to `text-align: left;`

For my guess, you may want to center the `<ul>`, so I style a bit more to make `<ul>` center.

```css
#div1 {
  border: black;
  border-style: inset;
  margin-top: 5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.div2 {
  border: blue;
  border-style: inset;
  height: 100%;
}

#salty {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 45em;
  height: 50em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 35%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-1"></div>

    <div class="col-md-10" id="div1">
      <p id="p1">
        <h1>My Cat Salty</h1>
      </p>
      <p id="p2">
        <h2>Salty is a floofball</h2>
      </p>

      <div class="div2"><img src="babysalty.jpg" id="salty" />
        <p id="p3"> This is my cat, Salty. </p>
      </div>

      <div class="div3">
        <ul>
          <li>Salty is a cat.</li>
          <li>This is a list item.</li>
          <li>This is a list item.</li>
          <li>Salty is fluffy.</li>
          <li>This is a list item.</li>
          <li>This is a list item.</li>
          <li>Salty also has a fluffy tail.</li>
          <li>This is a list item.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```